# Does the processor copy the same bloc from RAM to all caches?

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Upon a cache miss, the processor accesses RAM to read data and performs a prefetching operation, with data flowing from the RAM to the L3 cache, then the L2, and finally, L1.

Does the processor copy the same bloc in all cache levels during a prefetching?

Comment: Not necessarily, as the cache block line size may be different between the caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @erikeidt, and it also depends on the type of caches: inclusive or not.
If it is inclusive, each lower cache level can hold the data from the higher levels.
If not, the data can go directly from RAM to L1 cache.

Comment: In your example, L2 might get skipped if it was *exclusive* of L1d.  But it's common for caches to be NINE (not-inclusive, not-exclusive).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_inclusion_policy .  Normally all levels of cache get filled by a demand miss even if they're not required to maintain the inclusive property; that's more about what happens on eviction, that eviction from an outer level has to also evict from any inner cache that it's inclusive of.  It would be really rare I think to have a 3-level cache where L3 and L2 are exclusive of L1d.